# Trying To Save My Item To CoreData FrameWork

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to use CoreData to save my favourites locally and I have a set that acts as storage so that they will be accessed when the program terminates but I am not sure how to make my object persistent to do that. This is what I tried to do.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class PersistenceService {
    
    private init() {}
        
        static var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
            return persistentContainer.viewContext
        }

// MARK: CoreData
static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "playerModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
             
            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

static func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

**This is the object I want to save**

```
var item = CurrentPlayers(context: PersistenceService.context) //make it reference NSManagededContext so it can be saved

//this method adds to Favourites 
@IBAction func addToFav(_ sender: Any) {
               let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Favourite Added ", message: "\(name.text ?? "") is added to favourites", preferredStyle: .alert)
               alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
                    title: "OK",
                    style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
               { [self] _ in
                        FavouriteManager.shared.add(item)
                    })
               self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
               print("Favourite button Pressed")
           }
```

**This is where I want to store my objects**

```
import Foundation

class FavouriteManager {
    
    
    static let shared = FavouriteManager()
    
    var favSet: Set<CurrentPlayers> = Set()
    
    func add(_ player: CurrentPlayers) {
        favSet.insert(player)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: .passFavNotification,
            object: player
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want to save you call `saveContext()` on your PersistenceService class and the Set you have has nothing to do with Core Data so I am unsure what you are really asking.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it I just want my set to contain those fav objects even if the app terminates instead of losing them.

Comment: If you want your set saved to disk then you would need a specific entity for the set or have a boolean property set to true for only those you want to be included in the set. Unless of course I have misunderstood and yo want all your objects to be part of the set.

Comment: Yes everything added to the set must be saved.

Comment: Honestly I think we are talking past each other but my guess is what you want is to load all objects into the set when the app starts using a fetch request. No need to save the set itself since the content is stored in Core Data

Comment: Okay I have the objects in the set before it terminates but when it terminates CoreData does not save my objects I put in the set.

Comment: Well have you called save() on the managed context somewhere?